# MD5 é um hash seguro?

Tags: php, java, android

MD5 é um hash seguro?

Existe forma de reverter?

Caso não seja a melhor opção, o que vocês recomendam?

Aguardo sugestões...

Obrigada

Comment: Dê uma procurada aqui no próprio Stack Overflow que já existem diversas perguntas a respeito. Resumidamente, o MD5 não pode ser revertido mas, uma vez que o cálculo do MD5 de uma string resultará sempre no mesmo hash, é fácil buscar o texto aberto em uma lista de hashes MD5. Existem diversas alternativas melhores – a que eu recomendo é ter um salt por senha e criptografar a senha com esse salt e um algoritmo mais seguro, por exemplo Bcrypt.

Comment: Qual o propósito? Um hash pode ser usado para várias coisas, e para algumas delas o MD5 é razoavelmente seguro sim (embora normalmente ele seja combinado com outras primitivas criptográficas). O MD5 é vulnerável a colisões (não podendo ser usado em protocolos de assinatura digital), mas segue resistente a pré-imagem e 2ª pré-imagem (i.e. só pode ser "revertido" numa busca exaustiva). Ele também é bastante rápido, o que o torna inútil pra proteger senhas (ou outros textos curtos).